# Looking up a string in a dataset that aligns with a numerical value in its column with a formula

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

In Google Sheets, I would like my dataset on the right to display the information in a ranked order, from highest numerical value to lowest, from left to right.

Mockup of Desired Dataset:

[image]

I tried using Arrays envelop the numbers and strings, and then I used MAX and FIND to try and pull those strings from the top. The ranks after 1 would to find the next highest number and find their strings. however, it ended up only giving me the numerical value.

Answer (score 0):

*You may try:*

```js
=byrow(D3:U,lambda(Σ,if(counta(Σ)=0,,torow(sortn(tocol(D2:U2),6,,tocol(Σ),)))))
```

[image]